# Auto reconnect to wi-fi

Tags: wireless

When I open my laptop, it takes about 5 sec to reconnect to the wi-fi network. Is there a way for a faster connection? Maybe configure it to not disconnect when I close laptop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is impossible. Every time you will be disconnect when your adapter powers off. This times are:

- sleep
- hibermode
- close times.